react typescript component with conditional generic props infer type incorrectly
Hello I bumped into a situation where I want to conditionally type my Component by its props, but TypeScript works terribly with generics in that case.
Could you explain to me why specifically with Component,  TypeScript works bad, but if I try to create a variable const test:Props<{variant:"link"}>, it will infer type correctly?
import React from 'react';

type BaseProps = {
  variant: 'close' | 'link' | 'dropdown';
  text: string;
};

type CloseButtonProps = BaseProps & {
  onClose: () => void;
  onClick: () => void;
};

type LinkButtonProps = BaseProps & {
  href: string;
  isExternal?: boolean;
};

type DropdownButtonProps = BaseProps & {
  content: string;
};

type Props<T extends BaseProps> = T['variant'] extends 'close'
  ? CloseButtonProps
  : T['variant'] extends 'link'
    ? LinkButtonProps
    : DropdownButtonProps;

const MenuItem = <T extends BaseProps>(props: Props<T>) => {
  return null;
};

const element = <MenuItem variant="link" href="test" text="test"/>

As you can see, element cannot have href prop because it falls to DropdownProps, why?
TypeScript playground

Added the related github issue and more reasoning as to why it does not work

In your case you can simply use a Discriminated Union, instead of chained Conditional Types:
type BaseProps = {
  text: string;
};

type CloseButtonProps = BaseProps & {
  variant: 'close'; // Discrimant property with a unique literal value type in each member of the Union
  onClose: () => void;
  onClick: () => void;
};

type LinkButtonProps = BaseProps & {
  variant: 'link';
  href: string;
  isExternal?: boolean;
};

type DropdownButtonProps = BaseProps & {
  variant: 'dropdown';
  content: string;
};

You can now directly use the Union, without resorting to generic type parameter inference:
const MenuItem = (props: CloseButtonProps | LinkButtonProps | DropdownButtonProps) => {
  return null;
};

<>
  <MenuItem variant="link" href="test" text="test" />{/* Okay */}
  <MenuItem variant="dropdown" href="test" content="foo" text="test" />{/* Property 'href' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & BaseProps & { variant: "dropdown"; content: string; }'. */}
  {/*                          ~~~~ */}
  <MenuItem variant="dropdown" content="foo" text="test" />{/* Okay */}
</>

Playground Link

Note that in your example, const test:Props<{variant:"link"}> works because you explicitly specify the generic type parameter; it is not "inferred"; but then the conditional types indeed work.
If we explicitly specify the generic type parameter in the JSX in a similar way, it works as well:
// Okay if explicitly specifying the generic type parameter
<MenuItem<{ variant: 'link' } & BaseProps> variant="link" href="test" text="test" />

But even outside JSX, should you let TS trying to infer the generic type parameter, it fails as well:
// Error, does not infer correctly:
// Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'href' does not exist in type 'DropdownButtonProps'.
MenuItem({ variant: 'link', href: 'test', text: 'test' })
//                          ~~~~ 

Playground Link
You can simplify your Props type, as done in Tushar Shahi's answer, so that it does not need to inspect a deep type property, which easily fails as shown above.

EDIT: Ideally, the code should work as is. But type inference/narrowing for a generic parameter type and related conditionaly type does not work well. There is an open issue in TS repo.
Here is a smaller example reproducing the same:
type TypeEnum = "string" | "number" | "tuple"

interface KeyTuple { key1: string; key2: number; }

type KeyForTypeEnum<T extends TypeEnum> 
    = T extends "string" ? string
    : T extends "number" ? number
    : T extends "tuple" ? KeyTuple
    : never;



function doSomethingSwitch<TType extends TypeEnum>(type: TType, key: KeyForTypeEnum<TType>) {
    switch (type) {
        case "string": {
            console.log(key); //type of key is string | number | KeyTuple
            break;
        }
        case "number": {
            console.log(key); //type of key is string | number | KeyTuple
            break;
        }
        case "tuple": {
            console.log(key); //type of key is string | number | KeyTuple
            break;
        }
    }
}

Playground
Althout the generic type TType is being narrow using the switch statement, the related type key is still not being narrowed correctly.
This can be correlated to your example where although T would be passed correctly, T['variant'], the related type, can not be narrowed.
When used in type Props<T extends BaseProps> = T['variant'] extends 'close', T['variant'] is being inferred to as 'close' | 'link' | 'dropdown'.
And, the conditional will evaluate to false:

Hence, no matter what you try in the original example, the type returned from Props will be DropdownButtonProps.
Here is another related issue, with a feature request.
TO FIX:
One way is to remove the generics, as mentioned in another answer.
Another way to do it would be to remove the conditional type itself.
Simply Tweaking your Props and MenuItem so that the generic type has 'close' | 'link' | 'dropdown' as parameters instead of complete BaseProps object will make it work:
type Props<T extends BaseProps['variant']> = T extends 'close'
  ? CloseButtonProps
  : T extends 'link'
    ? LinkButtonProps
    : DropdownButtonProps;

const MenuItem = <T extends BaseProps>(props: Props<T['variant']>) => {
  return null;
};

Playground
The above works because the narrowing and all the conditions run on only one type (the generic parameter type) and there is no related type.
